# 'va_start' used in function with fixed args

Tags: objective-c, macros

I have `Logger.h` with following code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <asl.h>

#define LogDebug(format, ...){ \
  Logger(ASL_LEVEL_DEBUG, format,##__VA_ARGS__); }



#define Logger(LEVEL,format, ...) \
  LogLocal(LEVEL,format,##__VA_ARGS__);

#define LogLocal(LEVEL, format, ...) \    
  va_list arg_list; \
  va_start(arg_list, format); \
  // ...\
  va_end(arg_list); \
```

I call log from Obj-C as:

```
LogDebug(@"Name is called with flag: %@", collectName ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

However I get an error:

> 'va_start' used in function with fixed args

How to get rid of this problem?

**EDIT 1:**

I tried to call also: `AFLogLocal(LEVEL,format,...);` - same error

**EDIT 2:**

if I'll remove `asl_log` and replace with `NSLog` - it will work:

```
#define LogLocal(LEVEL,format, ...) \
NSLog((@"XXX: %s "  format), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, ##__VA_ARGS__);
```

**EDIT 3**

credits to `@Amin Negm-Awad`, replaced `LogLocal` with function in `.m` file as:

```
void LogLocal(int level, NSString *format, ...){

    va_list arg_list;
    va_start(arg_list, format);
    va_end(arg_list);
    NSString *formattedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:arg_list]; 
    asl_add_log_file(NULL, STDERR_FILENO); 
    asl_log(NULL, NULL, (level), "XXXX:  %s", [formattedString UTF8String]);     
}
```

works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use macros that are expanded. But they do not create a scope or a call on expansion. It's simple text replacement.

```
// Somewhere in a function
void f(void)
{
  …
  LogDebug(@"Name is called with flag: %@", collectName ? @"YES" : @"NO");
  …
 }
```

This will expand at the end to something like this:

```
// Somewhere in a function
void f(void)
{
  …
  // LogDebug(@"Name is called with flag: %@", collectName ? @"YES" : @"NO");
  va_list arg_list;
  va_start(arg_list, @"Name is called with flag: %@");
  // ...
  va_end(arg_list);
  …
 }
```

Since  `f()` takes no vargs, there are no vargs.

It might help to make `LogLocal()` a function, not a macro:

```
void LogLocal( int level, NSString *format, ... );
```

Implementation:

```
void LogLocal( int level, NSString *format, ... )
{
  va_list arg_list; 
  va_start(arg_list, format); 
  // ...
  va_end(arg_list);
}
```

To your Edit 2:

Yes, this works, because you do not touch the arg list, but pass the args to a function taking vargs. But you do not need that trick. Instead make `LogLocal()` a function and it will be called similar to `NSLog()` without any error.